# Create slide effect using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS framework and I am trying to get slide effect same as jQuery     provides, I did google too much but didn't find anything related to it. So if any one has any idea about that please guide me to achieve that thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) useful if you want to animate DOM object insertion (check the animate directive).

---- Update -----

Newer versions of Angular (1.1.4+ I believe) add a ngAnimate directive especially made for adding CSS animation to Angular apps. Check the offical docs (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate) or http://www.nganimate.org/.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use the jQuery slide, but wrap it in an angular directive.  Check the docs about directives and also [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB7hfvqyZpg&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not be using jQuery directly with Angular, even in directives. It is a last resort. Here is another good post on the topic here on SO.

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: I think the jury is still out on wrapping jquery on directives.

Comment: Link doesn't really apply to this.  OP is asking for a specific case.  Do you have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion ui.bootstrap  covers this issue, for instance this basic example http://surecode.me